# Get all instances of a string and include the text inbetween

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do a regex search of a large drug formulary. I need to match a specific drug's name and include all of the characters until the drug name is repeated again or EOF is reached.

The closest I've come is using positive lookaheads such as `QUILLIVANT.+?(?=QUILLIVANT)` however this is not capturing when there is only one instance of the word "QUILLIVANT". It also gets flagged as "Catastrophic Backtracking/Runaway Regular Expression" by an online regex test.

So given the input `blahblahblah Quillivant 40MG derp derp derp Quillivant 60MG/5ML Syrup durka durka durka` the return needed is `Array[0] = "Quillivant 40MG derp derp derp ", [1] = Quillivant 60MG/5ML Syrup durka durka durka`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue can be solved by adding a `|$` at the end of the lookahead to also account for cases when there is no `Quillivant` after a `Quillivant`:

```
/QUILLIVANT.+?(?=QUILLIVANT|$)/i
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kFDHL5/1).

To make the pattern more robust just [unroll the pattern](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop):

```
/QUILLIVANT[^Q]*(?:Q(?!UILLIVANT)[^Q]*)*/i
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kFDHL5/2)

The `[^Q]*(?:Q(?!UILLIVANT)[^Q]*)*` part matches any 0+ `Q`s and then any 0 or more sequences of `Q` not followed with `UILLIVANT` and 0+ chars other than `Q`. Basically, it means, that this part matches any text up to `Quillivant` or end of string.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I did some brief testing and it looks like this handles all my use cases. This saves me from doing a bunch of php butchery to accomplish my goal.